# Can I underline the text of a NSTextField from interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can I underline the text of a NSTextField from interface builder ?

So far, I've only able to change its color. Is there a way to underline it ?

thanks

Comment: check this out: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487290/iphone-uitextfield-with-rich-text

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you'd have to do it in code. For example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[myTextField attributedStringValue] mutableCopy];

[str addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

[myTextField setAttributedStringValue:str];

[str release];
```

Comment: This is a big help, though I ran into an error until I changed the value to: NSUnderlineStyleSingle

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString *strs = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:[btnPreviousTitle attributedTitle]];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [strs length]);
    [strs addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];
    [btnPreviousTitle setAttributedTitle:strs]; help me to make my NSButton with Underline text.

Answer (score 29):

**Valid only for iOS**

Yes, set attributed text, then select the text, right mouse click > Font > Underline

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that screenshot goes with NSTextField? I do not see such an option to set the title to be attributed and it seems like that screenshot relates to a button instead.

Comment: It should do that with every Attributed String field

Comment: I don't see an option for setting the string to be attributed. Are you sure that you are in an OS X app? Inside of Xcode when selecting a NSTextField I see the following: http://i.imgur.com/yTip3sq.png

Comment: Nope, sorry, I'm on iOS but I supposed that that having an `attributedString` property would have been reflected in Interface Builder like they do with the other controls...

Comment: Yeah, I figured you misread the question, might want to add a note that your answer is for UITextField and not NSTextField

Comment: although it is useful info, the question was about NSTextfield not UI something

Comment: Why is this answer here, and why are people upvoting it? Is it so hard to read the question title before answering?