# How to make an underlined text in UILabel?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, uilabel, underline

How can I make an underlined text in `UILabel`?

I had tried by making a `UILabel` with height **0.5f** and place it under the text. This line label is not visible when I am running my app in **iPhone 4.3** and **iPhone 4.3 simulator**, but it is visible in **iPhone 5.0 simulator** onwards. Why?

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to use CoreText

Comment: Can you please explain..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763757/core-text-tutorial see this answer it will helps you

Comment: I want to make the line with 0.5 thickness. Is it possible?

Comment: I dont know much idea about coretext but i think it is possible with Core text

Comment: [Swift extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36507060/1634890)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28721075/3497544

Answer (score 84, accepted):

#### Objective-C

**iOS 6.0 > version**

`UILabel` supports `NSAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello Good Morning"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                        range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];
```

#### Swift

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello Good Morning")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

**Definition** :

```
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)aRange
```

`Parameters List:`

**name** : A string specifying the attribute name. Attribute keys can be supplied by another framework or can be custom ones you define. For information about where to find the system-supplied attribute keys, see the overview section in NSAttributedString Class Reference.

**value** : The attribute value associated with name.

**aRange** : The range of characters to which the specified attribute/value pair applies.

Now use like this:

```
yourLabel.attributedText = [attributeString copy];
```

---

#### iOS 5.1.1 <  version

You needs `3 party attributed Label` to display `attributed text`:

1) Refer [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) link. Its best third party `attributed` `Label` to `display` attributed `text`.

2) refer [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) for third party `attributed` `Label`

Comment: But I need this underline in ios 4.3 also... :(

Comment: i want to remove underline if set...how can i do this

Comment: Here's small optimization: With your swift version line `let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello Good Morning")`, the data type of `attributeString` is implied by what it is being assigned to, so it's redundant and you can omit it, as follows: `let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello Good Morning")`

Answer (score 14):

I am using Xcode 9 and iOS 11.
To make the UILabel with an underline beneath it.
You can use both
 1. Using code 
 2. Using xib

Using code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I am iOS Developer"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                        range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];
lblAttributed.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Using Xib:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We can also use for button too.

Answer (score 5):

### The Designer Way - Highly Customisable Version

I personally prefer to customise my design(s) as much as possible. Sometimes, you will find that using the built-in underline tool is not easily customisable.

Here is how I do it:

<kbd>1</kbd> First I create a UIView for the underline. You can then choose your background color, either in IB or programmatically. Constraints are key here.

[image: Create Your Underline view]

<kbd>2</kbd> Then, you can customise the underline as much as you like. For example, to adapt the width of the underline for better visual effect, create an outlet connection to a constraint in Interface Builder

[image]

<kbd>3</kbd> You can then easily programmatically customise your underline view. For example here, to give you an idea we will make the underline 20 px wider than the title "Breads":

```
var originalString: String = "Breads"
let myString: NSString = originalString as NSString
let size: CGSize = myString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
self.widthUnderlineTitle.constant = size.width + 20
```

<kbd>Results:</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). If you're allowed to use 3d-party components just replace your UILabels with TTTAttributedLabel where you need it (drop-in replacement). Works with iOS < 6.0!

Answer (score 2):

**Swift extension on UILabel:**

Still needs improvement, any thoughts are welcome:

```
extension UILabel{

    func underLine(){    
        if let textUnwrapped = self.text{
            let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
            let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: textUnwrapped, attributes: underlineAttribute)
            self.attributedText = underlineAttributedString   
        }   
    }
}
```

One of the cons i can think of right now is that it will need to be called each time text changes, and there is no actual way of turning it off...

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0**

```
var attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello Good Morning")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSRange)
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourLabel.text ?? "")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```