# Adding underline to UILabel attributed string from the storyboard fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

1. From the storyboard I select the UILabel in question
2. Then in Attribute Inspector > Label > [I choose] Attributed
3. Also in Attribute Inspector > Label > Text> [I select the content]
4. Then I click on the font icon and choose underline

Basically, any change that I select from the Fonts window that pops up does not take effect.

Has anyone ever successfully add underline from the storyboard?

Note: I already know how to do this in code. I want to avoid adding code.

Comment: Yes, I have successfully added underline from storyboard many times. Please see my answer below in response to your question with the screenshot

Answer (score 261):

Here is the solution in storyboard:
Open the Attribute Inspector (make sure label is selected), Change the dropdown value from 'Plain' to 'Attributed'. Now a a small text editor will be visible under the font of the label. Select the text of the label, right click and change the font to 'underline'.

I also have attached a screenshot and successfully underlined a text using storyboard in XCode 7.0.1[image]

Comment: This is the real solution, how is this not accepted??

Comment: Using Xcode 7.1.1 it has a bug: when setting the underline the font shrinks by 4 and you can't change the size of the text anymore

Comment: @OhadM It is not a bug I think. When you change the text to "attributed" actually the font family changes and it seems the font has shrunk. You can change the size of the attributed text by selecting it in the small text editor in Attribute Inspector. Note that you have to select the whole text first

Comment: I actually tried to change the size and it has no effect.

Comment: Why is this answer not marked as the accepted one? It worked perfectly for me still (2 years after the answer was written). GIVE THAT GUY A GREEN CHECKMARK ALREADY!

Answer (score 61):

Underline your text in TextEdit(cmd-U) and copy-paste it in Attribute Inspector > Label > Text > Attributed.

Comment: Hmm. This worked first, and then all the elements on my screen just disappeared. There was no error in the console!. I undo until before pasting text from text edit, and screen was back to normal... XCode 6.2 Beta.

Comment: For me this only works when copy-pasting out of rich text editors. TextEdit does not do the job for me, no style is copied with the text, only the characters.

Comment: You deserve a beer for this +1

Answer (score 23):

Select label -> Attribute editor -> Title = Attributed

Select the text of the label in the text view in the editor -> Right click -> Font -> check Underline

If the change is not visible -> resize the label

Comment: Good Idea :) I like your Answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can make text underline from storyboard like this.
But when you change the text programatically it will override and underline will gone.
So if you have to change the text on runtime. Do this.

**For Swift 3**

```
 let text = myLabel.text
 let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, (text?.characters.count)!)
 let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text!)
 attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
 myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

**For Swift 4**

```
  let text = myLabel.text
  let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: (text?.count)!)
  let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text!)
  attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
  myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave it set to plain. Make all of your changes. Then change it to attributed.

Answer (score 0):

### The Designer Way - Highly Customisable Version

I personally prefer to customise my design(s) as much as possible. Sometimes, you will find that using the built-in underline tool is not easily customisable.

To do something like the following, I have posted an example in [How to make an underlined text in UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122207/how-to-make-an-underlined-text-in-uilabel/40955014#40955014)

[image]