# How do you set multiple attributes on text (UILabel, UIButton, etc) within storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

When dealing with an element that contains text, you can set the text to attributed to allow for more customization. But this never actually works. There is the little font icon that opens a window where you can select a font, a color, bold/italic/underlined, font size, etc. Changing anything in this window does nothing (at least for me, tested on multiple macs and multiple ios devices over the past two years).
There are some smart solutions as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099736/adding-underline-to-uilabel-attributed-string-from-the-storyboard-fails) for example. But aside from having to open external software just to edit some text in a button, these solutions are not exactly complete. Usually some attributes can be copied from a rich text editor, but not all the attributes (in my case, I can't find an editor that copies font, font style AND text color). Also, most of these editor don't have a lot of fonts available.

So, to get to the point: I want to have a UIButton, with the text "Wachtwoord vergeten?", white, bold and underlined, Helvetica Neue Medium 18pt. How do I do this? I just want to get this working, but a more general solution would be great for future readers.

Comment: This is the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30242307/1801544

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding underline to UILabel attributed string from the storyboard fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099736/adding-underline-to-uilabel-attributed-string-from-the-storyboard-fails)

Comment: @Larme Not really, it does not work for multiple attributes at once.

Comment: @MarkHim I explained that the answers there do not work 100%, so not a duplicate.

Comment: I managed to put a text "Label", with the first letter in Red, Bold, Underlined and bigger, and the rest in black normal.