# Underline UIlabel so the underlining always reaches the bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

What I want to achieve is to have `UILabel` underlined but in a specific way.

I know how to make `UILabel` underlined, but since this is going to be a dynamic text, I don't know how long it will be.

Anytime the label enters a new line, I'd like to make the underlining align with the one above regardless of the text length.

I sketched it up to give you a better notion of what I actually try to achieve:

[image]

What is your opinion, how to approach such problem?

Should I add the white line as `UIView` anytime text skips to another line?

Or maybe add some whitespace in code when the text lengths is shorter than bounds of current line?

Comment: You mean you want underline till your text?

Comment: Use NSMutableAttributedString. Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122207/how-to-make-an-underlined-text-in-uilabel

Comment: Attributed string will underline only my text and will not align to the left bound, correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: for that you have to create custom line view

Comment: @Anilsolanki Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: ok let me create it for your and post

Comment: Please find my answer with code.I have created label with underline till bounds

Comment: ok thanks, now I'm going to translate it into swift first, then test :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97394/discussion-between-anil-solanki-and-dcdc).

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have came up with solution with custom label class and override drawRect Method in that custom class of UIlabel.

**CustomLabel.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomLabel : UILabel

@end
```

**CustomLabel.m**

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0f);
    float Left = self.center.x - self.frame.size.width/2.0;
    float Right = self.center.x + self.frame.size.width/2.0;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, Left, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, Right, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

In Your Class Just import this custom Class.

```
 #import "CustomLabel.h"

 ////// you can create labels now which are having underline to bounds.

-(void)CreateCustomLabel
{
    CustomLabel *custom = [[CustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, SCREEN_WIDTH-40, 50)];
    custom.text = @"Your Text Here";
    custom.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:custom];
}
```

Comment: does not work, just draws rectangle around the UILabel

Comment: check out screen shot with obective c code . . I can send zip of code

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set text for you label then call this method :

```
- (void)underlineLabel:(UILabel*)lbl {

if (![lbl respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
    return;
}
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText;
if (!lbl.attributedText) {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lbl.text];
} else {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:lbl.attributedText];
}
long len = [lbl.text length];

    [attributedText addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,len)];


[attributedText addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];//Underline color

lbl.attributedText = attributedText;
}
```

Comment: may I ask for swift implementation?

Answer (score 0):

```
func underlineLabel(label: UILabel) {

    if !lbl.respondsToSelector("setAttributedText:") {
        return
    }

    var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()


    if !(lbl.attributedText != nil) {
        attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:label.text!)
    }

    else {
        attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
    }

    let str = label.text;

    let len = str?.characters.count;


    attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, len!))

    attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value:1, range: NSMakeRange(0, len!))
    //Underline color
    lbl.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

Comment: this is not working, it underlines till the last character, not till the end of a line